# DDNS ssh gets stuck after “SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent” message

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, sshd, dyndns

I am trying to set up ssh logging from across the internet. I have a DDNS `noip.com` domain which I can successfully ping and it reaches my host. The DDNS is configured straight on my router and the relevant ports have been forwarded (port 22). When I execute `ssh -vv myuser@foo.ddns.net -p 8001` I get the following:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "foo.ddns.net" port 8001
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to foo.ddns.net [123.456.789.100] port 8001.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to foo.ddns.net:8001 as 'myuser'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
```

I've disabled the router firewall, the OS firewall, I've edited `hosts.allow` and `hosts.deny` to allow everything. How can I get ssh to authenticate successfully or give me an error message of sorts?

Comment: Can you ssh from `my host` to `myuser@127.0.0.1:8001, i.e. from your machine foo.ddns.net to itself? The log shows you are establishing the connection. The next line should be SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received.

Comment: @icarus yes I can. Just slight correction - 8001 is the external port which gets forwarded to port 22 on the host so will be `ssh myuser@127.0.0.1' without 8001. I also have keyless ssh setup between hosts on my LAN.